# Find out which GPS location in DB is closest to user's current location

Tags: php, mysql, gps, coordinates

I'm writing a PHP script that will output a SELECT form field with a list of locations retrieved from a database. I want this list to be sorted by distance from the current location  (using HTML5 geolocation).

How do I know which location is closest?

The locations are stored in the database with a Latitude and Longitude field.

Comment: So what is not working with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the distance to each using the Haversine formula and then sort the results. The Haversine formula is implemented in many programming langauges [here](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe). The formula is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).